# Selecting common values and adding them SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table called Test. It has three columns Fn(varchar),Un(number),INS(date). What I am trying to do is select all rowsfrom the table and get the sum of common values in column Fn.

Example

```
     Fn Un     INS
     ---------------
     1   6   9-Jan-2017
     2   8   9-Jan-2017
     1   5   4-Jan-2017`
```

I am trying to sum common values based on Fn column so the result would be

```
Fn Un 
1   11
```

I am trying to understand how to CASE IF ELSE in Oracle. But not able to add them because the INS date is different for both of them. Is there any way to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need group by like below:

```
select fn, sum(un) as total
from t
group by fn
order by total desc;
```

You can use `Aggregate functions`(Average, Sum, Max, Min..) in sql with `group by`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `group by`:

```
select fn, sum(un)
from t
group by fn
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try LISTAGG function for INS column

```
     SELECT Fn, SUM(Un) as Total, LISTAGG(INS, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Fn) as INSs
     FROM T
     GROUP BY Fn
     ORDER BY Total DESC;
```